# React native push notification getting data from API

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification

I'm new to react native and I need some help.

I need to implement a feature that the application informs the client if it has an appointment on the day and if it does, notify him, if not, not notify.

However, I believe that the application needs to check in the API if it has any scheduling and if it has to check if it is on the scheduling day and if it is, send a notification to the client

Correct me if I'm wrong

I'm using react-native-push-notification

But I can't make the logic for this to happen, I can offer my code so they can help me

Comment: *Another suggestion*: You can opt to go with [react-native-one-signal](https://github.com/OneSignal/react-native-onesignal). Actually, it's way better than react-native-firebase. But you have to use these libs if to send the notification in a certain condition when you have a backend. You have a backend? PS: Can you provide some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion**:
You can opt to go with the **react-native-push-notification** with **firebase** so that You can able to send the push notification whenever you want through the blackened.
Firebase documentation:[Cloud Messaging](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage)